# My computer keeps making quick beeping noises then restarts when I try to put in new RAM

Tags: memory, shutdown, reboot

I looked every where to try and find the solution to this problem but I can't.

I downloaded Watchdogs yesterday and it was kinda of laggy so I try to put some more RAM, but when I start up the computer the computer just beeps quickly then restarts and the cycle continues on

[EDIT]
Specification
GIGABYTE GA-Z87-HD3
Intel i5
GTX 650TI
4BG RAM
(Trying to add 2GB ram)

Comment: This sounds like... a RAM issue! Try just 1 stick of the new RAM (no 'old' RAM). Try running MEM Test... Make sure all the RAM is seated correctly. Since you already searched, the phrase you're probably looking for is "beep codes". This then let's you see what the beep code means.

Comment: You provided information about the motherboard and the CPU what about the memory? I have serious doubts that additional memory will help with the performance issues. Your GPU just barely meets the Recommended System specifications for `Watch_Dogs`. Even increasing to 6GB or 4GB ( not even sure which one please specify ) might not help.  I assume you have upgraded the Nvidia drivers to the drivers that increase `Watch_Dog` performance and decrease the quality of the game to the lowest possible?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a Faulty RAM stick, it could be one of a few things, if the stick itself was exposed to static I.E. a carpet and so on it may have killed it, also some computers don't allow for RAM sticks to have different speeds this incompatibility will cause the beep code, finally it could be that your old stick of RAM coincidentally died so check either stick by booting the computer with one stick of RAM at a time and running MEM Test as the comment suggests.

You should be able to find a lot of information on beep codes type in your computers motherboard make and model into google alongside Beep codes this should tell you what exactly the computer is telling you!

Comment: It isn't the sticks I tried them both and they seem to be fine by themselves.

Comment: then check the speed of each stick if it is different then that may be your problem if the RAM reads at different speeds it is sometimes not supported by your motherboard @user327273

Comment: If they are at different speeds is there anything I can do to change the speeds?

Comment: no Im sure its built in to the stick itself if you baught a new stick of RAM take it back to the shop and ask for the same speed as you current stick

Comment: @user327273 Has this issue been resolved?

Answer (score -1):

you can change the RAM speed in the bios but you can only lower it, for ex. if u have 1600Hz u can lower to 1333Hz, but u can't bring it up to 1800Hz.But even this didn't resolve my problem.I set both my ram sticks to 1333Hz and it still boots up with the beeping sounds and restarts.Individually, the ram sticks work fine in whichever ram slot, but no together